# Minify many js files to one with yuicompressor

Tags: javascript, yui, minify

I have 2 js files: `test1.js` and `test2.js`. I want to minify it with `yuicompressor` to one file.

I tried:

```
./yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar --nomunge test1.js test2.js -o test3.js
```

But there is only one file in `test3.js`. How can i minify multiply files to one?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't use this compressor but I simply concatenate the files with another command before I launch the minifier.

Comment: I would recommend using [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) instead.

Comment: Please refer answers written for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517849/compressing-multiple-javascript-files-with-yuicompressor/27416747#27416747

Answer (score 1):

Merge them first using either:

- copy and paste to a new file
- script in the editor you're using collecting the file contents to a new file
- use a file `join` command from command line or batch file

Then apply the the YUI compressor.